# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ASPSnippets_Pager is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I'm trying to use custom pagination in asp.net gridview as in http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Pagination is not getting added and When I checked in console I get error `"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ASPSnippets_Pager is not a function "`

Could someone explain what the issue is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            GetCustomers(0);           
        });
    });
    $(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
        GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
    });

    function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
        var oemID = $("#<%=ddlOEM.ClientID%>").val();
        var oemName = $("#<%=ddlOEM.ClientID%>").text();
        var pageSize = 30;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Patches.aspx/GetPatchList",
            data: '{oem:' + oemID + ', pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ',pageSize:' + pageSize + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
function OnSuccess(response) {
 var pager = xml.find("Pager");
        $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
           ActiveCssClass: "current",
           PagerCssClass: "pager",
           PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
           PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
           RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
        });
 };
    </script>   
<div class="Pager"></div>
```

Comment: There was conflict with another .js script(vendor.js) which caused the error to show. Now everything looks fine